# How to add internal links to Suite Metadata on Robot-Framework report.html?

Tags: python, robotframework

On my suite I create a file with some extra information that may be needed for future reference. it is possible to add an internal link and show it on **report.html** as a link?. for example have below **${image_info}** as a link to the actual file that is under a results directory?

```
Set Suite Metadata    IMAGE    ${image_info}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, robot supports some limited formatting, including the ability to embed links. For example, to include a link to a file you could do something like this:

```
set suite metadata  IMAGE  [something.html|${image_info}]
```

For more information see the section [Documentation formatting](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#documentation-formatting) in the robot framework user guide, and particularly the subsection [Urls](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#urls)